# Cannot mount local directory in container though path exists

Tags: docker

I am having a frustrating issue
I am running

```
docker run --name=thl001  -p 1001:8888 thl-runtime -v /Users/test/Desktop/thl-docker/dockerruntime:/opt/thl
```

and I confirm that both paths exists
but when I run it I get

```
[FATAL tini (7)] exec -v failed: No such file or directory
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker arguments need to go before the image name. Arguments that follow the image name are container arguments rather than Docker arguments.

```
docker run --name=thl001  -p 1001:8888 -v /Users/test/Desktop/thl-docker/dockerruntime:/opt/thl thl-runtime
```